# Static underlined lined and dont understand?

Tags: c#

Edit*****
I fixed it by adding at the end which allows the code to work with keeping everything the same

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DisplayMainMenu();
        }
```

---

I have written some code for a simple menu system. Without `static void Main(string[] args)`, the rest of the static statements aren't underlined, but without the `Main` line nothing shows and I'm confused on what to do.

Part of the code which I'm using but wont show anything:

```
class Program
{        
    public static class PlayerSelections
    {
        public static int Age;
        public static string Name, Character, GameType, Cup;
    }

    static void DisplayMainMenu()
    {
        int menuChoice;
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("* Welcome to the Player Selection Menu *");
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("* 1. Name and Age                                          *");
        Console.WriteLine("* 2. Player Selection                                      *");
        Console.WriteLine("* 3. Game type                                             *");
        Console.WriteLine("* 4. Cup selectiom                                         *");
        Console.WriteLine("* 5. Print out                                             *");
        Console.WriteLine("* 6. Exit                                                  *");
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Please specify your menu choice: ");
        string menuChoiceString = Console.ReadLine();
        menuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(menuChoiceString);
        DisplayMainMenuChoice(menuChoice);
    }

    static void DisplayMainMenuChoice(int selection)
    {
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("You have selected Enter your Name and Age");
                EnterNameAndAge();
                DisplayMainMenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("You have selected the Player Selection Menu");
                PlayerSelectionMenu();
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("You have selected the Game Type Selection Menu");
                GameTypeSelectionMenu();
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("You have selected the Cup Selection Menu: ");
                CupSelectionMenu();
                break;
            case 5:
                Console.WriteLine("You have selected the Print Out Selection Details: ");
                PrintOutSelectionDetails();
                DisplayMainMenu();
                break;
            case 6:
                Console.WriteLine("You have selected exit the program");
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("You have made an illegal selection");
                DisplayMainMenu();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Images for context:

- [With `static void Main(string[] args`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnT2u.png)
- [Without `static void Main(string[] args`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQbGH.png)

Comment: Please don´t post images of cod. Instead paste the **relevant** code directly int your question. Apart from this: which VS-version are you using?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Sorry i was only doing it to show the red underling and im using 2017

Comment: And what exactly don´t you understand? Pretty easy: a `static` method can´t contain another `static` method. A `class` on the other hand **can**.

Comment: Since all programs need a `static void Main` entry point, just add one to your code above, and call your `DisplayMainMenu` method from it: `static void Main() { DisplayMainMenu(); }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you put your static methods inside `Main`. Put them inside the class, next to `Main`.

Comment: I suppose OP already knows **how** to solve it as in 3rd image, but not **why** he needs this.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Considering the second (last) image doesn't show a `Main` method (nor does the sample code in the question) and the OP said, *"without the Main line nothing shows"*, I think Tolik is onto something here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function `DisplayMainMenu()` inside another function `Main(string[] args)`which is not possible and results in an error.
You have to define the functions outside the function and then you can call it inside the `Main`. Then, the underline will disappear.
In C# it is not possible to define a function like you can do that in Javascript...
You must define a function as a member of a class and then you are able to call it from other functions.

Answer (score 0):

While local functions were introduced on C#7, they can´t be `static` themeselves.

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.comdotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions):

> Unlike a method definition, a local function definition cannot include
>   the following elements:
>
> - The member access modifier. Because all local functions are private,
>     including an access modifier, such as the private keyword, generates
>     compiler error CS0106, "The modifier 'private' is not valid for this
>     item."
> - **The static keyword. Including the static keyword generates compiler
>     error CS0106, "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item."**

Having said this you could do the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        InnerMethod(); 
        void InnerMethod() { ... } // local function defined within DoSomething
    }
}
```

For `static` this is not possible, this is why you get a compiler-error when you define a local function within `Main`.

Anyway local functions are just syntactic sugar that are compiled to normal methods within your class. So the above is compiled to something similar to this:

```
class MyClass
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        InnerMethod(); 
    }
    void InnerMethod() { ... }        
}
```

which is what you would have to use before C#7.

Comment: I've removed the static and now nothings showed up but is showing no errors?

Comment: @AhrenHart And isn´t this what you want? Btw. **which** `static` did you remove? From `Main`? From `DisplayMenuChoice`?

Comment: I've removed it from the DisplayMenuChoice but when i run  the program nothing shows

Comment: @AhrenHart Well, you have to **call** the method somewhere. You **need** a `static void Main`, which is the applications entry-point. From there you could call your method, be it static or not. I strongly suggest to read a book about C# pr read some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're trying to define a static function inside of another static function, which doesn't make sense.

The keyword `static` means a class that is non-instantiable, or a method that belongs to a class that cannot be invoked on an object of that class.

While you can have local functions starting with C# 7.0, you cannot declare the nested function as static for the reasons stated above.

I would either remove the `static` keyword from the local functions, or create a class and define them as static methods in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it by adding:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DisplayMainMenu();
        }
```

right at the bottom which allowed me to keep everything the same and everything works now.